# Считывание текстового файла при помощи fscanf

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, ввод

Есть такое задание:
Даны исходные данные о сотрудниках IT компании. Даны два бинарных отношения для всех сотрудников. Первое отношение “работал вместе”, второе - “психологически не совместим”. Необходимо сформировать новую команду для нового проекта. Начальник выбирает ответственного за проект (Team Lead) и задает количество сотрудников для проекта. Программа выбирает заданное количество сотрудников на проект, при этом они желательно должны иметь опыт общей работы с выбранным (Team Lead) и точно психологически совместимыми между собой.

Данные читаются из следующего текстового файла:

```
4  
Савельев Самсон Алексеевич,0,1,0,1,0,0  
Константинов Василий Владимирович 0,1,0,0  
Соколова Марина Михайловна,0,1  
Покровский Наум Юрьевич,
```

Формат файла: первая цифра - количество строк в файле(кол-во работников), дальше каждая строка содержит имя работника и массив 0 и 1(их количество=количество строк ниже*2)

код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class KURSA4
{
  private:
    struct worker
    {
        int worked_together;
        int psy_compatible;
    };
    int n;
    worker** ptr;
    string* name;


  public:
    void print_matrix()  //отладочная функция, не забудь удалить,
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << name[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << ptr[i][j].worked_together;
            }
    }
    KURSA4()
    {
        FILE* file = fopen("H:/KURS/list.txt", "rt");
        fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
        ptr = new worker*[n];
        name = new string[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = new worker[n];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char temp[50];
            fscanf(file, "%[^,]", temp);
            name[i] = (const char*)temp;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < n ; j++)
            {
                worker temp;
                fscanf(file, "%d,%d", &temp.worked_together, &temp.psy_compatible);
                ptr[i][j].worked_together = temp.worked_together;
                ptr[j][i].worked_together = temp.worked_together;
                ptr[i][j].psy_compatible = temp.psy_compatible;
                ptr[j][i].psy_compatible = temp.psy_compatible;
            }
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    KURSA4 a2;
    a2.print_matrix();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Похоже я не понимаю логики работы fscanf ибо выводит лютую хрень: имя только 1-го работника, а вместо чисел их адреса. С форматом файла и форматной строкой эксперементировал, пробовал и с запятыми считывать и без, результат все тот же.

```
Савельев Самсон Алексеевич  
Савельев Самсон Алексеевич  
Савельев Самсон Алексеевич  
Савельев Самсон Алексеевич-842150451-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-842
150451-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-842150451-858993460-858993460-858
993460-858993460-842150451Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Как поправить это считывание   вообще возможно ли это - считывание такой "треугольной структуры"(обусловлена тем что отношения симметричны)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас при чтении в буфере остается несчитанные символы - `\n` при чтении строки, `,` после чтения фамилии, так что происходит просто сбой: ну не начинается число с запятой, хоть тресни! :) Соответственно, `fscanf` вернет 0 - кстати, почему вы **нигде не проверяете** возвращаемые значения? они бы сказали сразу очень многое!

И, кстати, в вашем примере после Константинова пропущена запятая...

Чтоб не возиться с вашей кучей указателей, я исправил их на векторы - в простейшем варианте, чтоб не переписывать все :)

Словом, вот нечто, что компилируется и работает. Думаю, разберетесь, что изменено, а главное, почему и зачем :)

Конечно, это просто исправления; само построение программы, гм... оставляет желать лучшего. Как и способ представления информации в файле, кстати.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class KURSA4
{
  private:
    struct worker
    {
        int worked_together;
        int psy_compatible;
    };
    int n;
    vector<vector<worker>> ptr;
    vector<string> name;


  public:
    void print_matrix()  //отладочная функция, не забудь удалить,
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << name[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << ptr[i][j].worked_together;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    KURSA4()
    {
        FILE* file = fopen("list.txt", "rt");
        fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
        while(fgetc(file) != '\n');

        ptr.resize(n);
        name.resize(n);
        //ptr = new worker*[n];
        //name = new string[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ptr[i].resize(n);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char temp[50];
            fscanf(file, "%[^,]", temp);
            name[i] = temp;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < n ; j++)
            {
                worker temp;
                fscanf(file, ",%d,%d", &temp.worked_together, &temp.psy_compatible);
                ptr[i][j] = temp;
                ptr[j][i] = temp;
            }
            while(fgetc(file) != '\n');
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    KURSA4 a2;
    a2.print_matrix();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Действительно вектора пожалуй удобнее массивов будут, попробую переписать все под них.Этот код выдал исключение в 29 строке: stream!=nullptr, с выводом что-то не так(

Comment: http://ideone.com/VJDgHg - смотрите здесь; единственное, тут данные берутся не из файла, а из `stdin`, но это не принципиально. Ошибок вроде не заметно. У меня при компиляции VC++ 2015 тоже работает без ошибок. Да, и еще - файл после работы надо бы закрывать.

Comment: Студия вроде тоже 15... странно, буду думать

Comment: Все разобрался, после бессонной ночи не замечаю элементарных вещей...

Comment: Ну, тогда, если ответ устраивает - ставьте птицу :)

Comment: Да вроде бы код правильный, на ideone у вас скомпилировался, казалось бы подправить цикл вывода(чтоб проверить правильность считывания), и можно работать дальше... но ровно тот же код, на том же сайте при попытке скомпилироватся у меня выдает: превышено время компиляции, в студии компилируется без ошибок, но консоль при этом просто пуста... Я начинаю верить в мистику.Попробую разобраться вечером на свежую голову, птицу обязательно поставлю)